# Connecting Sharepoint Online using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am new to Powershell and trying to learn it and have started from scratch.
I have a task to retrieve some information from Sharepoint Online and i am supposed to do it with Powershell, however whenever i try to run the cmdlet  **Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline** i get the following error.

*Install-Module : Administrator rights are required to install modules in 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'.
Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install*

Is it because I don't have the global administrator rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have administrator rights on local system you can try it with:

```
-Scope CurrentUser
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7#example-5--install-a-module-only-for-the-current-user

Answer (score 0):

You require Local Administrator rights on the local machine, this has nothing to do with Sharepoint or PowerShell.
If  you do have these rights, right click the PowerShell executable and choose Run As Administrator.

Comment: I did try that and it gives a pop-up to add in the admin details which I assume my organisation hasn't given me. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?